# Render a FineUploader button inline

Tags: php, css, fine-uploader

So I'm using FineUploader, and it works perfectly fine. There's just one issue though. I've been trying to render it inline, so that I can have text before and after it.

I tried using `<span id='btnupload'></span>` with the following CSS:

```
#btnupload {
   display:inline-block;
   *display:inline;
   width:150px;
}
```

but it seems to break the uploader. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

P.S. I don't need the Drag & Drop, or even the progress bar and upload list to display. I just want the button to work, with no other elements.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to troubleshoot your issue.  What do you mean by "break(s) the uploader"?  Please provide specifics regarding your problem (including the browser you are using) along with functional code.  JSFiddle.com is a good resource for sharing a live example.  As it stands, everything looks fine to me.

Comment: You're actually right! In [creating the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMgQv/) I realized that I was overriding my own CSS.

Comment: @RayNicholus could you please show me how I can hide the progress bar, spinner, file list and everything else aside from the button itself? The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/BMgQv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your question now is to hide all of the UI elements provided.  Note that Fine Uploader has two modes.  You are using the mode that includes a default but customizable UI, FineUploader mode.  If you want to only utilize the API and ensure Fine Uploader does not create any UI elements, use FineUploaderBasic mode instead.  Have a look at the [readme](http://docs.fineuploader.com) for more details.